# Showing top 5 with grouping

Tags: 2013, list, sorting, grouping

I have a list that collects customer sales data (multiple records can contain the same customer). I am trying to create a view that will show the Top 5 customers based on sales. I need to have the customers grouped, and the sales data summed. Is there an OTTB way to accomplish this?

[image]

So I want to show the top 3 customers based on sales

Comment: What are the fieldtypes of your Sales info and What View with Grouping and Filtering have you tried? It helps to show screenshots of those settings in your question.. all I can answer now is Yes.. but..

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible OOTB since [Aggregation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms468626.aspx) has no sorting parameter. This might be because the values are never stored it is calculated on the fly. You can achieve this through some code. Have a look at [this](http://sympmarc.com/2009/05/20/showing-subtotals-in-a-dvwp-sorted-by-the-subtotals/)

Answer (score 0):

You display item in batch of 3 items, you can set item limit in **modify view setting**.

You need to set **item limit of 3** so each group will show top 3 data.

[image]

It will look like

[image]

It will display paging. If you want to remove that, just apply css over that.

To display top items, you can **sort it** by ID in asc in desc order.

Comment: That still does not sort the "Groups" (or in my case "Customer") by sales. I want the highest sales at the top.

Comment: @MattC you can sort it by sales field.

Comment: That is how my original screenshot is sorted